# Can I post a public message to my Facebook application?

Tags: .net, facebook, c#-4.0, facebook-c#-sdk

Can I post a public message to an my application, and if so, will it automatically send that message to the public feeds of all users of the application who have authorized it for `offline_access,publish_stream`?

*Note*: When a user clicks my application's "Subscribe" button they are explicitly doing so to get informational updates published to their feeds, so I request `offline_access,publish_stream` and they have to authorize that.

This question is about sending one message to everybody at once instead of iterating over each user of the application.

I think something like this can be done with Pages.

Comment: @zerkms: public message for the feed - the users have agreed to subscribe to updates from the app. I'll clarify the question also. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Technical part: yes, it is possible to send to your application feed a message through facebook api.

To perform this you need to give "publish_stream" permission to the account you're sending the message from. After this you can schedule messages sent without authentication.

Sociel part: the users will see your messages in their feeds until they explicitly hide your application from streaming.